# GridView adding column with button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to add column with button in GridView ? i tied with asp:button i got error also i tried asp:ButtonField i got this error:

**"Error Creating Control - narudzbaGridType 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ButtonField' does not have a public property named 'ID'.**

but i gave ID name to my Button field  **asp:ButtonField ID="example"**

```
<asp:GridView ID="narudzbaGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Let" HeaderText="Let"/>
            <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="Kolicina" HeaderText="Kolicina"/>--%>
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: It's an error because ButtonField doesn't have an ID property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TemplateField` like this (add to columns block):

```
<asp:templatefield headertext="Author Name">
    <itemtemplate>
      <asp:button id="buttonl"
        Text= 'Click Me'
        runat="server"/> 
    </itemtemplate>
  </asp:templatefield>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi you need to add an `TemplateField`. Everybody like use `ImageButton` but if you want use other control go ahead.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
  <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnEditar" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/iconos/Image.png" CommandName="edit" ToolTip="Edit">
     </asp:ImageButton>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <ItemStyle Height="8px"></ItemStyle>                                
</asp:TemplateField>
```